# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'

Tags: python, pandas, rpy2

I'm trying to `import pandas as pd`. I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'`. Why? I use pandas 0.20.1 + python 3.6 x64 + Windows 7 .

Example:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.0'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'bob'

import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import pandas.rpy.common as com
import pandas as pd
```

Returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\doc\GitHub\proj\src\open_rdata.py", line 19, in <module>
    import pandas.rpy.common as com
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.rpy'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`pandas.rpy` module was deprecated and later removed. It does not exist in the version you are currently using.

You can either downgrade your pandas version, or better yet, have a look at the new `rpy2` project.

From pandas documentation:

> Up to pandas 0.19, a pandas.rpy module existed with functionality to
>   convert between pandas and rpy2 objects. This functionality now lives
>   in the rpy2 project itself. See the updating section of the previous
>   documentation for a guide to port your code from the removed
>   pandas.rpy to rpy2 functions.

You can see the rpy2 documentation [here](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/), and panda's reference for it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html).

edit: per Analytical Monk's comment, corrected the phrasing to refer `rpy2` as a different library, and not a part of pandas

Comment: There's no `pandas.rpy2` module. `rpy2` is a separate python library. Documentation for the same is provided here: https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/